# Android - View pager back function not working in first two tab

Tags: java, android

I used a viewpager with a tablayout in an activity. It has 3 tabs, The issue is when selected tabs 1&2 back button is not working, and it’s  not able to go to the previous activity. And, in the 3rd tab the back button is working and I am able to access the previous activity.

I have given finish code in onBack function. Then also it’s not going to the previous activity.

The code below describes how I set the viewpager and tablayout in my activity. Tell me how to set back button for Tab 1 & Tab 2.

```
class MainActivity
{

    TabLayout.Tab firsttab = tabs.newTab();
    firsttab.setText("Personal Details");
    tabs.addTab(firsttab);

    TabLayout.Tab secondtab = tabs.newTab();
    secondtab.setText("Employment");
    tabs.addTab(secondtab);

    TabLayout.Tab thirdtab = tabs.newTab();
    thirdtab.setText("Documents");
    tabs.addTab(thirdtab);


    Servicepageadapter adapter = new Servicepageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabs.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tapposition = tab.getPosition();

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    private class Servicepageadapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs ;
        public Servicepageadapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int tabCount) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.mNumOfTabs = tabCount;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    boolean  isbackstack = true;
                    PersonalFragment tab1 = new PersonalFragment().newInstance("", "","");
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    if (!isbackstack) {
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    }
                    transaction.commit();
                   return tab1;

                case 1:

                    boolean  isbackstack1 = true;
                    EmploymentFragment tab2 = new EmploymentFragment().newInstance("", "","");
                    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    if (!isbackstack1) {
                        transaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                    }
                    transaction1.commit();
                   return tab2;

                case 2:
                    boolean isbackstack2 = true;
                    DocumentsFragment tab3 = new DocumentsFragment().newInstance("", "","");
                    FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (!isbackstack2) {
                        transaction2.addToBackStack(null);
                    }
                    transaction2.commit();
                    return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're performing `FragmentTransaction`s in `getItem`.  You shouldn't do that: `getItem` is only supposed to create and return the `Fragment`, and let `FragmentPagerAdapter` itself handle the rest.

If you want the default back functionality (leaving the `Activity`/going to the previous `Activity`), you can simply remove all the transaction-related code.  If you want more custom functionality (such as changing tabs), then you can [use `OnBackPressedDispatcher` to customize it](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back).